# jenkins: windows xp, windows 7 slave cannot execute commands

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have a Arch Linux master that drive 2 arch linux slaves, 1 windows xp slave and 1 windows 7 slave. Linux part is all ok, I managed in some way to start windows slave using automatic execution and slave.jar. I have an external program that need to be executed and it's installed on c:\program files (x86) on windows7 and on c:\programs on windows xp. 
I went on path variables and inserted the two path on the two systems, but when I try to run jenkins build it says "command not found"

I tryed to place 2 bat files in c:\ poining to the right place, based on every system, but it says c:\build.bat command not found. I can see the file in the right place...

How do you manage executables placed in different places on different computers? 
there's a better way to run the program?
I can change everything about this installation, the only thing I need it to find a way for starting that program.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the way jenkins start the job on the slave. I used "Execute shell" and some program are executed. I changed "Execute shell" with "Execute windows batch command" and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the changes you made to the system path were actually saved? Make sure both of the slaves have been rebooted and then test this via a standard command line window.

If the program you're trying to execute is actually on the path, you could also look at the [Envfile Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin).

Comment: Yes, I can run the command from cmd.exe. I edit correctly the path env variable. it looks like that it isn't correctly interpreted by jenkins. As I told before I run the slave as current user, so the path variable to edit is the one of the user correctly set. I'll try to see what's Envfile plugin. thank you for your hint

Answer (score 0):

After adding new paths to your environment variable PATH you need to restart jenkins slave service in order to allow it to use these new PATHs.